# Partially bold text in TextBlock

Tags: c#, wpf

I get text from DB in single line. For example "Hello my name is the Developer".
I need the part of this text will be in bold and put it in TextBlock.

For code I use:

```
overview_text.Text = overView;
```

Where overview_text TextBlock is TextBlock and overView is string from db.

I can alter the DB string as I wish but I need single string, for example what I need is:

```
"Hello my <bold> name </bold> is the Developer"
```

Can you please help me with this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are many ways to achieve your desired result. The `RichTextBox` way is *far* from optimal and dates back to Windows Forms controls, where this was more difficult to achieve. Generally, the best class to use for this in WPF would be the [`Run` class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.documents.run.aspx).

Some of the many benefits of using the `Run` class include the fact that its `Text` property is bindable and we can apply all of the usual text manipulation properties on it as you can see from the example below:

```
<TextBlock FontSize="16" Padding="25">
    <Run Text="Here is some " />
    <Run Text="BOLD" FontWeight="Bold" />
    <Run Text=" and " />
    <Run Text="ITALIC" FontStyle="Italic" />
    <Run Text=" and " />
    <Run Text="COLOURED" Foreground="LightGreen" />
    <Run Text=" text in one TextBlock" />
</TextBlock>
```

[image]